# A tiny bug in reputation display

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/62699/ldigas?tab=accounts

shows my reputation on SuperUser as 10288 but https://superuser.com/users/2127/ldigas shows it (my guess) as it should be.

Just reporting ...

Comment: The accounts lists haven't been updated yet. They're planning on [doing that this weekend](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124203/141525).

Comment: @animuson - Ah, ok. I'm not following this site regularly, not familiar with the updates, so just thought I'd point it out.